# WebM playback faulty on Android 2.3.6

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, nexus-one, video

When I open a 720p ".webm" file on the "Movies" app in Android 2.3.6 (Nexus One) it displays only one frame and plays the audio correctly. How to fix it? Should I try a lower resolution file?

Answer (score 2):

I just found out it happens only with HD videos. 480p and 320p videos play normally. 
The problem is caused by the Hardware Decoder.
When I use a player like MX Video Player, that allows me to choose a SW decoder, the playback is normal.